# Debugging - emacsclient: error accessing server file "server"

Tags: emacsclient, daemon

I got the not terribly helpful error message recently trying to connect `emacsclient` to a emacs daemon using tcp sockets.

`emacsclient: error accessing server file "server"`

Looking at the source, its not obvious what is going wrong - http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lib-src/emacsclient.c?h=emacs-24#n1356

Any suggestions?

(I tried to recompile emacs and attach a gdb, but I didn't have much luck with that)

Comment: Which OS? Have you checked the permissions on the server file?

Comment: OSX.  Permissions are `-rw-------`, where I am the owner. What should the permissions be?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's necessary, but mine is `-rwx------`.

Answer (score 3):

For a socket the permissions should be `srwx------` - the `s`, meaning "socket" is the important part. (I also tried removing the executable bit, it didn't make a difference).

Since the permissions are `-rw-------` you are not using a socket. There are two ways to fix that, (1) make sure you are using a socket (2) tell emacsclient that it's not a socket.

(1) Make sure the value of `server-use-tcp` is `nil` (which happens to be the default). It has to be `nil` at the time you start the daemon, changing it later only serves to confuse you.

(2) Tell emacsclient to connect to a tcp file using `emacsclient --server-file=SERVER`.

I recommend the former.